Build the whitakers-words dictionary with Alire
First of all I want to apologize for something wrong I will say, I'm new to Ada and Alire.
I am trying to use the whitakers-words dictionary (https://github.com/mk270/whitakers-words) for a personal project in a React application.
I am still looking for a method to run it locally.
The documentation of the project suggests to use the GNAT compiler, but reading the Ada documentation I have read that everything has been moved to Alire that has new commands.
Following the documentation (here: https://alire.ada.dev/docs/#migration-of-an-existing-adaspark-project-to-alire) I have created the workspace for the project and run the "alr build" command.
Nothing works.
I don't understand what is the main gpr file to run.
The project documentation suggests to run
gnatmake -O3 words
gnatmake -O3 makedict
gnatmake -O3 makestem
gnatmake -O3 makeewds
gnatmake -O3 makeefil
gnatmake -O3 makeinfl
gnatmake -O3 sorter

Does someone know how to run the whitakers-words in the alire environment?
Thanks a lot

The whitakers-words hasn't migrated to Alire, so you don't actually need it. What you need is a GNAT toolchain, and you can obtain it either from Alire or using other methods, like those specified in https://www.getadanow.com/ or https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Installing#GNAT,_the_GNU_Ada_Compiler_from_AdaCore_and_the_Free_Software_Foundation
If you use Alire to install the toolchain, the relevant section to consult in Alire documentation is https://alire.ada.dev/docs/#toolchain-management

See also Ada 95: Modifying output of dictionary program.

Actually Whitaker's Words used to be available in Alire a long long time ago. The old manifest is here: https://github.com/alire-project/alire-index/blob/stable-1.3.0/orphaned/wh/whitakers_words.toml but it is incompatible with current Alire.

@Alex has requested restoring the project's manifest. As your platform may be unavailable, please [edit] your question to include this detail. If you elect to build locally, also [edit] your question to include any problems you encounter.

I've just submitted a PR to reindex Whitaker's Words in Alire. Once that one is merged, you will be able to simply
$ alr get --build whitakers_words
$ cd whitakers_words*
$ alr run

Truth is, since this project depends on make, it is a bit unorthodox to index, so it is not a good example for a newcomer. A simple project that just used a single GPR file can be "Alirefied" rather easily with alr init --bin <name> --in-place --no-skel.
